# Interpolated coordinates prevent static google map from loading

Tags: google-maps, pug, google-maps-static-api

On a web page I can display a static map using something like.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/
staticmap?center=51.455041,-0.9690884&zoom=17&size=600x300
&sensor=false&markers=51.455041,-0.9690884&scale=2")
```

However when I try

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
center=#{location.coords.lat},#{location.coords.lng}
&zoom=17&size=400x350&sensor=false&markers=
#{location.coords.lat},#{location.coords.lng}&scale=2"
```

Where #{location.coords.lat}, and #{location.coords.lng} are interpolated strings from a controller file, from this line.

```
coords: {lat: 51.455041, lng: -0.9690884},
```

All i see is a broken image.

I know that I can access lat, and lng, because when I create a paragraph

```
p #{location.coords.lat}
```

it displays as "51.455041" when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is from pug's [doc](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation):

> Previous versions of Pug/Jade supported an interpolation syntax such
>   as:
>
> ```
> a(href="/#{url}") Link This syntax is no longer supported.
> ```

If you are using your link as `img` source, the correct syntax is:

```
img(src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + location.coords.lat + ',' + location.coords.lng + '&zoom=17&size=400x350&sensor=false&markers=' + location.coords.lat + ',' + location.coords.lng + '&scale=2')
```